# Show webform confirmation on same page as the form

Tags: webforms

How can I show a confirmation message on the same page as the form instead of redirect? Right now I see a a link for "Go back to form" and I want to see the confirmation and webform.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Drupal 7, you can simply enter the confirmation message (do not enter a URL) on the Webform config. This message will display above the form after completion.

Answer (score 0):

Webform 8.x-5.x supports displaying the confirmation message above the form.

[image]